# Unable to create content

Tags: users

I created a test account and added it to a numer of roles. Some of those roles (not all) have permissions to create content. I am unable to create or edit any content, but am able to view all published content.

When I log in as user/1 I am able to create new content.

What permissions am I missing in order to be able to create new content when logged in as a newly created user?

Comment: Have you tried to reorder your roles at `/admin/people/permissions/roles` as described?

Comment: Thank you @enzipher

How should I reorder the roles? Sorry, I have tried to find doco on the importance of reordering the roles but couldn't find anything :(

Comment: The order should be least permissive to most permissive, i.e. your admin role at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you @enzipher
Reordering the roles fixed the issue! How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some scenarios, re-ordering the roles on the Roles page might help solve access issues.

To reorder the roles, go to `Administration > People > Permissions > Roles` (`/admin/people/permissions/roles`).

Click and drag the far left handle for each role to re-order the roles by least permissive to most permissive, i.e. your admin role at the bottom.

Example:

- anonymous user (locked)
- authenticated user (locked)
- moderator
- administrator

For reference, here is the help text for the Roles page:

> Roles allow you to fine tune the security and administration of
>   Drupal. A role defines a group of users that have certain privileges
>   as defined on the permissions page. Examples of roles include:
>   anonymous user, authenticated user, moderator, administrator and so
>   on. In this area you will define the names and order of the roles on
>   your site. It is recommended to order your roles from least permissive
>   (anonymous user) to most permissive (administrator). To delete a role
>   choose "edit role".
>
> By default, Drupal comes with two user roles:
>
> Anonymous user: this role is used for users that don't have a user account or that are not authenticated.
>   Authenticated user: this role is automatically granted to all logged in users.

Drupal handbook on [Managing access control with permissions and user roles](http://drupal.org/node/22275).

Answer (score 0):

The only permission a role needs in order to create new content for a content type is *Create new content*.  This permission must be set for each content type you want the role to be able to create content for.

If your user belongs to a number of roles, then it is - in a default Drupal 7 configuration - neccessary that at least one of the roles have this permission granted.  Unless you have some node access module installed that breaks with the Drupal paradigm of grants being accumulative (e.g. **Deny Access**), then it should not matter if some of the roles the user belong does not have this granted.

Comment: Thank you @GisleHannemyr

One of the roles I've assigned the new user to does have the permission to Create new content (Basic page & Webform) in admin/people/permissions. However, I am unable to create new content when logged in as this newly created user...